# How to extract value from Data dictionary like values in CSV file in Python Panda data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have Header in CSV file with the data dictionary format like `{"Id":"endDate","timeZone":"Z"}` in column A , `{"Id":"status"}` in column B, `{"Id":"ipAddress"}` in column C in Panda Data Frame.  How Can I show only Values in respective column in CSV file?

[image]

I tried to replace this code but seems not working.

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace(r'{"Id":"$', '')
```

I want to show only Values like in Column A > endDate, B > status, and C >  ipAddress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZpQk.png)

Expected output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j515p.png)

Answer (score 0):

You've not actually provided the first row of your CSV which is the column names.  I've reconstructed (also chose pipe separated).  `json.loads()` to convert a string into a `dict` then extract key value you want as column name in a dict comprehension

```
import json
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""{"Id":"endDate","timeZone":"Z"}|{"Id":"status"}|{"Id":"ipAddress"}"""), sep="|")
df1 = df1.rename(columns={c:json.loads(c)["Id"] for c in df1.columns})
df1.columns
```

### output

```
Index(['endDate', 'status', 'ipAddress'], dtype='object')
```

### enhanced

- do not rename columns that do not have **Id** key
- deal with columns that are not a `dict`

```
import json
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""{"Id":"endDate","timeZone":"Z"}|{"Id":"status"}|{"Id":"ipAddress"}|{"NoId":"skip"}|notJSON"""), sep="|")
def decode(text):
    try:
        return json.loads(str(text))
    except ValueError:
        return {"Id":text}
df1 = df1.rename(columns={c:decode(c)["Id"] for c in df1.columns if "Id" in decode(c).keys()})
df1.columns
```

Comment: Ty Raymond, These are the header rows(Column name/ first row) only pulling from some other application and showing in this way. Also there are 868 column Headers like this in csv file (I just showed example in question). Can we do something like loop and show only VALUE where ID found.

Comment: there is already a loop in `dict` comprehension.  have updated to ignore as noted and also deal with column names that are not JSON